# Flask render form values

Tags: forms, flask, rendering

I have a question about rendering form results. When i submit the form i want to show the term below the form. what did i wrong ?

Now wehen i submit the form i get a 200 Status Code and no error message. But the term dosent show up in the defined place.

```
# app.py

@app.route('/search')
def search():
    return render_template('search/index.html')


@app.route('/search<q>')
def results(q):
    return render_template('search/index.html', term=q)


# search/index.html

{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<div>
<form method="get" action="">
    <input type="text" name="q" id="">
    <input type="submit">
</form>

{{ term }}

</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have confused path parameters (which Flask routes parse out and pass to the view) with query parameters (which are available in `request.args`).  Remove your second route and update the first to access the query.

```
from flask import request

@app.route('/search')
def search():
    term = request.args.get('q')
    return render_template('search.html', term=term)
```